# Can't make JQuery's .show and .hide work

Tags: jquery

I have a problem using `.show` and `.hide` in jQuery. Basically I want two options to appear once you hit the register button, this is the code:

HTML

```
<div id='register'>
    <form>
        <input type='button' class='register-button' name='register-button' value='R e g i s t e r !'>
    </form>
    <form id='register-type'>
        <span class='register-type-background'> </span>
        <input type='button' class='register-type-band' name='register-type-band' value='Band'>
        <input type='button' class='register-type-user' name='register-type-user' value='User'>
    </form>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#register-type').hide();
$('.register-button').click(function(){
    $('#register-type').show();
   });
});
```

And more HTML:

```
<head>
<title> Title </title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheet.css' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type='script' src='javascript.js'> </script>
</head>
```

Comment: remove `type='script'` or make it `type='text/javascript'`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the top two sections http://jsfiddle.net/yHQsD/

Comment: You are aware that jQuery's at version 1.10 now, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is [fine as it is](http://jsfiddle.net/mattytommo/s55tx/), but your problem is your actual `script` reference:

```
<script type='script' src='javascript.js'> </script>
```

There is no `type='script`, it needs to be `type='text/javascript'`, change it to be:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='javascript.js'> </script>
```